# Display system info on mobile running Symbian

Tags: c++, mobile, usb, symbian, cpu-usage

I have to write this C++ application that will run on a phone running Symbian, and it must show some OS infos like CPU temperature, memory usage,..etc. I know that there are some libs for that, but the problem is those infos must be displayed on the phone when i connect it to the system via usb port. The question is how? is there any libs out there ?! or is there a better approach to that ?

Comment: Also, are you supposed to show the information _of_ the phone, or of the connected computer?

Comment: i'm targeting Symbian. the information is about the connected computer

Comment: I don't think there exists any library in Symbian that would be able to read the PC's CPU temperature.

Comment: Actually it's a C++ library that would do that, and i will compile it for Symbian

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear which CPU/OS you want to analyze and show on the phone: the Symbian OS or PC's OS.

But you can make your Symbian phone talk to PC via USB: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/TSS000601_-_Serial_communication_over_USB_on_S60_3rd_Edition_devices

For retrieving the PC's CPU/OS information you will probably need an additional software running on that PC. Additionally in your case such application should be talkin to USB as well (otherwise your phone will be useless).

If you're meaning extracting Symbian OS information, that you can take a look at this sort of articles: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/TSS000038_-_How_can_I_check_how_much_free_memory_is_available%3F

Comment: thanks for the infos. yes a "server" will run on the PC and will provide some sort of services which contains a bunch of infos about the PC's OS/CPU. But this won't be a cross-plateform app, everytime i connect the phone to the PC_target i must have a "server" runing on the target.